# how to retrieve data from mongo db in lumen

Tags: laravel, mongodb, lumen

i have a lumen project that is using mongo db now i want to access the data and do some logic on them my object in mongo is like below :

```
    _id: ObjectId('602cfb30bc865100073f0e56'),
    serviceType: 'normal',
    segment: 'Basic',
    steps: {
        'step1': 1,
        'step2': 2
    }
```

nnow in my laravel application i do it like below :

```
      $data = DiscountRule::first();
        dd($data);
```

and the result is like below :

```
 App\Models\Rule\DiscountRule {#183
  #collection: "discountRules"
  #connection: "mongodb"
  #dispatchesEvents: array:2 [
    "saved" => "App\Utility\Mongo\Listeners\ModelSaved"
    "deleted" => "App\Utility\Mongo\Listeners\ModelDeleted"
  ]
  -events: []
  #primaryKey: "_id"
  #keyType: "string"
  #parentRelation: null
  #table: "discountRules"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:4 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId {#150
      +"oid": "602cfb30bc865100073f0e56"
    }
    "serviceType" => "pishropost-regular"
    "segment" => "Basic"
    "steps" => array:2 [
      "itemCount > 0 and itemCount <= 9" => 60000
      "itemCount > 9" => 0
    ]
  ]
  #original: array:4 [
    "_id" => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId {#150}
    "serviceType" => "pishropost-regular"
    "segment" => "Basic"
    "steps" => array:2 [
      "itemCount > 0 and itemCount <= 9" => 60000
      "itemCount > 9" => 0
    ]
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

now it returns the data as `array` but i want to return as object so that i can for example use `$data->segment` and get the data in segment . any idea how can i return data from mongo as object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the first line of your `dd()`. The type of the return is `App\Models\Rule\DiscountRule`. All the underlying arrays, is how `Laravel` models works internally with setting attributes.

So you should be able to do.

```
$rule = DiscountRule::first();
dd($rule->segment);
```

Comment: i dont know what happened but i havent foolishly tried the -> after swtiching from get to first () thanks any way :D